# How to set java compiler for ANT in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, version

In NetBeans I have a build.xml that said me with this:

```
<target name="print-version"> 
   <echo>Java/JVM version: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
   <echo>Java/JVM detail version: ${java.version}</echo> 
</target>

ant -f C:\\DTE-master -Dbuild.compiler=javac1.7 print-version
print-version:
Java/JVM version: 1.8
Java/JVM detail version: 1.8.0_51
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

But I need to compile with jdk 1.7 u21

For that purpose I have introduced this command:

```
<xmlbean classgendir="${classes.dir}" srcgendir="${generated.dir}" fork="yes" executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javac.exe">
```

But still is not compiling with jdk 1.7 u21

What is wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code above to complie one project to jar file:

```
<target name="your name app" depends="jar">
        <property name="store.jar.name" value="your name app"/>
        <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
        <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
            <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
                    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
        </zip>
        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
</target>
```

And about jdk 1.7, you can change it by right click on project, choose properties. In Sources/Binary format, select JDK 7 then click ok. Your project will be run in jdk 1.7